# Which CSS should I apply to appear tool tip over a text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display tooltip on click of textbox.
What i did is:

CSS:

```css
.tooltip {
    background-color:#000;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    padding:10px 15px;
    width:200px;
    display:none;
    color:#fff;
    float:right;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:12px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.input1 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #DFDFDF inset;
    clear: left;
    min-height: 45px;
    position: relative;
}
.textfield {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: medium none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-size-adjust: inherit;
    font-stretch: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-variant: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
.label {
    float: left;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-align: right;
    width: 26%;
}
```

JS:

```css
$(function () {
    $("#help_form :input").tooltip({
        position: "center right",
        offset: [-2, 10],
        effect: "fade",
        opacity: 0.7
    });
});
```

HTML:

```css
<div id="help">
    <form id="help_form" class="help_form" action="/me/problem" method="post">
        <div class="input1">
            <label class="label" for="issuetitle">Title</label>
            <input class="textfield" type="text" name="issuetitle" title="must be 100 characters long" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Actually by setting width of textfield = 30%. We can able to see tooltip. But because of some restriction i don't want want to do it. Is there any other way to do it by using it tooltip comes over textbox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's a fiddle if anyone wants to test: http://jsfiddle.net/gUcLX/
I can see the tooltip just fine. What's the issue?

Comment: I just want to display tooltip over the textbox. Currently it display behind textbox. so is there any css which i need to add in .tooltip

Comment: And because of some restrictions i am not able to do any changes to the css of textfield and label. So what i can do is in the tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use jquery for tooltip, like this,

```
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  });
  </script>
```

And if you want to know more about it then refer this link,

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have a correct html : put a `<style>`after your head.
Then you need to load the tooltip plugin you want to call with `.tooltip()`.
Then check for your console and javascript errors.

But maybe you have stripped down your code to post here.

If it's the case, try with a `display: block` on your `.tooltip` declaration and check if you can see it.